# VueJS2 and Laravel Auth (and history mode)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, html5-history, vue-router, vuejs2

I'm creating a backend system that I want to use VueJS2 for with a Laravel backend. The problem i'm facing at the moment is integrating this all together while keeping the 'tidy' URLS (no hashbangs) utilising Vue's history mode:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,

  mode: 'history'
})
```

I am a fan of the way Laravel handles Authentication and as such i've tried to use that in this system as an entry point into the SPA but doing so breaks the history mode.

In my routes file i've added a Vue capture route that works to allow hard refreshing of the browser and back button etc and this works fine:

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('home');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

However in order to use Laravel Auth i've added the following check, which works to force you to login before accessing anything else but breaks the history mode:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
        return view('home');
    })->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
}
else {
    // the home controller has the auth middleware in the __construct
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
}
```

I've tried adding middleware onto the end of the vue capture route but it didn't seem to do anything.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get SPA working with any backend, you should use Api authentication based on JWT.

This is Laravel docs about it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

This is good package for this purpose: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: I'm not sure if that is only for API work rather than customer facing? When I say backend I mean more of an intranet type system where it's accessible by the client directly through the browser. So I want them to get to the login page, login with their credentials and then enter the SPA only after that. Or is this still the solution?

Comment: This is still the solution. You have to understand that auth has to be handled by SPA. I mean that Login page has to be in SPA, then you have to send credentials to backend, then get back JWT from backend and store it in SPA and then attach JWT in headers of every http request to authorize your request.